# Best practices to classify recurring patterns using an LSTM or GRU

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks

I'm working with acoustic data (filterbank features) and I want to build a neural network to detect claps using an LSTM (or a GRU) with a binary output (present/abscent), and I'm wondering about how I should prepare my data before feeding them to the RNN.

If I have 20 seconds of claps (separate claps separated by ~ 0.1 seconds) what is the difference between :

1. Feeding the network a series of N claps as one example (with variable N : 1, 2, .., 10, ..) + padding with zeros to fit the longest sequence.
2. Feeding the network multiple examples of 1 clap.

My problem is not restricted to claps but covers patterns that can be observed as separated occurrences, periodic sequence of occurrences, variable-length-period "quasi-periodic" sequence of occurrences, etc.

Unlike an ergodic HMM, an RNN doesn't have any loops to "jump back" to a previous "acoustic state", so what should-I do with this kind of data ?